# Can I get RabbitMq connection id from my Python/kombu client?

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, kombu

When I run this command:

```
rabbitmqctl list_connections pid
```

I get output like the following:

```
<rabbit@my_box.2.1234.0>
<rabbit@my_box.2.1235.0>
```

Is there a way to read this pid from my kombu client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not expose this kind of internal details through AMQP.

You can get many informations about connections using the [management plugin and its REST API](https://raw.githack.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/master/priv/www/api/index.html). Here is an example:

```javascript
// JSON returned by http://localhost:15672/api/connections
// ...
{
    "connected_at": 1458292870638,
    "client_properties":
{   
    "product": "RabbitMQ",
    "copyright": "Copyright (c) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.",
    "capabilities":
    {   
        "exchange_exchange_bindings": true,
        "connection.blocked": true,
        "authentication_failure_close": true,
        "basic.nack": true,
        "publisher_confirms": true,
        "consumer_cancel_notify": true
    },
    "information": "Licensed under the MPL. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "platform": "Java"
},
"channel_max": 0,
"frame_max": 131072,
"timeout": 60,
"vhost": "/",
"user": "guest",
"protocol": "AMQP 0-9-1",
"ssl_hash": null,
"ssl_cipher": null,
"ssl_key_exchange": null,
"ssl_protocol": null,
"auth_mechanism": "PLAIN",
"peer_cert_validity": null,
"peer_cert_issuer": null,
"peer_cert_subject": null,
"ssl": false,
"peer_host": "127.0.0.1",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"peer_port": 54872,
"port": 5672,
"name": "127.0.0.1:54872 -> 127.0.0.1:5672",
"node": "rabbit@localhost",
"type": "network",
"channels": 1,
"state": "running",
"send_pend": 0,
"send_cnt": 108973,
"recv_cnt": 99426,
"recv_oct_details":
{   
    "rate": 288892.8
},
"recv_oct": 5540646,
"send_oct_details":
    {
        "rate": 1912389.8
    },
    "send_oct": 36669998
},
// ...
```

However, PIDs are not exposed either through this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve? Do you need more informations from this REST call for instance?

Comment: I am testing how my application handles lost connections. For that, I need to delete my connection. Currently I delete it manually via rabbitmqctl. It would be nice to automate this test. To keep automated testing environment lean, we would like to get by with absolute minimum, not to install additional tools.

Comment: I don't know Kombu, but if you can get the source TCP port, then you could drive the firewall to block the connection. I think it would be easier compared to asking RabbitMQ.

Comment: I'll give it a spin. Thanks!